# Best way to call an action via an ajax call

Tags: c#

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#companyList").change(function () {
            var comp = $("#companyList").val();
            //          var url = "/Logon/fillLocation/" ;
            var url = '@Url.Content("~/Logon/fillLocation")';
            $.ajax({



                url: '@Url.Action("fillLocation", "Logon","JayPeeEmpPortal")',

                type: 'Post',
                data: { Comp_Code: comp },

                success: function (data) {
                    var markup = "<option value='0'>Select Location</option>";
                    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                        markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
                    }
                    $("#ddlLocations").html(markup).show();
                },
                error: function (reponse) {
                    alert("error : " + reponse);
                }
            });

            //         $.getJSON('@Url.Content("/Logon/fillLocation")', { Comp_Code: comp });
            //         $.post(url, { Comp_Code: comp });

        });
    });
```

and the below code is my controller code

```
[HttpPost]  
        public JsonResult  fillLocation(string Comp_Code)
        {


            var locList = db.LOCATION_MASTER.Where(l => l.COMP_CODE == Comp_Code).Select(l => l).Distinct();

                 List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
                foreach (var t in locList)
                {
                    SelectListItem s = new SelectListItem();
                    s.Text = t.LOC_NAME .ToString();
                    s.Value = t.LOC_CODE.ToString();
                    items.Add(s);
                }

                return Json(items);
           }
```

It is running fine while running with visual studio but throuthing error after hosting on my local machine having iis 5.1 xp service pack 3

Comment: Error:[object object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve the issue myself
Actually there was some iis configuration required.

As i added the .* extension in configuration
there i just needed to uncheck the checkbox "CHECK THAT FILE EXIST"

i did this and my application is running fine..